# Syntax for inlining return value of call

Tags: bash

While you can inline output of a program as parameters

```
$ echo $(ls)
cpp python bash
```

or as a temporary file

```
$ echo <(ls)
/proc/self/fd/63
```

I wonder how you can inline the return value with a similar syntax, so that it echoes the return-value of `ls` that it works like this:

```
$ ls
$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: Inline means that you want to suppress or redirect the return value?

Comment: `ls > /dev/null ; echo $?`? I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here...

Comment: @Azeem yes, the program ``ls`` should be executed and the return value, which is 0 in most cases, should be redirected to echo as a normal parameter

Comment: BTW, in general, there's no need for this because needing to capture an exit status is rare in and of itself. For the common case, one need only know "did this fail or not?" to branch on, so you can use `if my_command; then ...` to branch based on whether exit status was 0 or not without ever expanding `$?` at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
ls_retval=$(ls >/dev/null 2>&1; echo "$?")
```

If you want to encapsulate that:

```
# define a function...
retval_of() { "$@" >/dev/null 2>&1; echo "$?"; }

# and use it
ls_retval=$(retval_of ls)
```

As for "with a similar syntax", though -- the shell has the syntax that it has; there doesn't exist "retval substitution" (as of bash 4.4, or POSIX sh as standardized in POSIX Issue 7).